# How should i completely separate the legend with the pie chart for some distance in Core plot graph pie charts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have implemented a pie chart on iPhone application by following the [Rayenderlich CORE PLOT tutorial for PIE CHART](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

I implemented al these following methods as followed in the tutorial

```
-(void)initPlot {
      [self configureHost];
      [self configureGraph];
      [self configureChart];
      [self configureLegend];
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here i **have some issues**,

if the number of projects increases the lagend frame is always moved to top (with the increasing the height it doesnt increase at bottom) of the pie chart, at some point happens like in figure 3,4

i need to **move the legend table bellow the graph instead of beside the graph**
i tried with frame and legendDisplacement but no result found

How should i completely separate the legend with the pie chart for some distance

bellow the pie chart

Comment: What about some TableView underneath the pie chart that shows the legend?

Comment: which legendAnchor are you using ? Maybe using the oposite one, increasing the height will increase at bottom.

Comment: i tried with all the anchors bottom top bottomleft etc etc

Comment: Off topic: i think a pie chart it's not the right choice for the type of data you are dysplaing.

Comment: Another think, i just think there's no space in the screen to fit all the legend, maybe you can try using 1 column legend and a small graph, or a scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Use autolayout or adjust the frame of the chart's subview manually

Comment: Adjust the frames of label, if not possible, create label frame according to the size